# Parse PFUser login after logout

Tags: parse-platform, logout, pfuser

Problem: Logging out **user A** and then logging in **user B** on the same device

> 1) [PFUser logOut] user A
>
> 2) then login user B
>
> 3) After login user B the of user B [PFInstallation currentInstallation] is the one for user A!

So I get back the wrong **PFInstallation** for the **user B**.
Has anyone seeing this problem?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a problem, it's a misunderstanding. You're assuming that installations are related to users, but they aren't. Installations are related to devices. Installations don't have a link to any user as standard.

If you want to build a relationship between an installation (device) and a user you can, but you need to manage that relationship when the user logs in and out on different devices.